# Kinect DK Create Recording

Tags: azurekinect

Just received the new Kinect DK and installed the SDK on a W10 machine, then run

```
C:\temp>k4arecorder.exe -l 5 output.mkv
libusb: error [winusbx_open] could not open device \\.\USB#VID_045E&PID_097C#000041292112#{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED} (interface 0): [5] Access is denied.
[2019-07-03 16:53:10.760] [error] [t=9816] D:\a\1\s\extern\Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK\src\usbcommand\usbcommand.c (305): find_libusb_device(). Unable to open LIBUSB at index 0
[2019-07-03 16:53:10.761] [error] [t=9816] D:\a\1\s\extern\Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK\src\depth_mcu\depth_mcu.c (68): usb_cmd_create(USB_DEVICE_DEPTH_PROCESSOR, device_index, NULL, &depthmcu->usb_cmd) returned failure in depthmcu_create()
[2019-07-03 16:53:10.762] [error] [t=9816] D:\a\1\s\extern\Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK\src\sdk\k4a.c (129): depthmcu_create(index, &device->depthmcu) returned failure in k4a_device_open()
Runtime error: k4a_device_open() failed
Runtime error: k4a_device_get_serialnum(device, serial_number_buffer, &serial_number_buffer_size) returned 1
```

The cmd window was started in Admin mode, as was the viewer. Seems I cannot record on W10, but it works as described in Ubuntu 18.04. Seems it's an access condition, but not sure where.

Answer (score 1):

the reason you cannot open the device is because you connected it to the wrong port. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/Kinect-dk/troubleshooting#usb3-host-controller-compatibility and try to connect the device to a different USB port.

Answer (score 1):

We are working to try to make this error clearer. Access denied from libusb could also be due to the handle already being in use by another instance. On Windows you may also have the camera disabled (either you our a company policy). Check Settings -> Privacy for the global camera state.